# Measurements HC-SR04 outputs different values when I incorporate serial commands in my program

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, sensors

I'm experiencing something really weird. 
I'm using a Pi3 and I have a program that does ultrasone readings and writes serial commands.
The thing is, when I enable both of these things in my program, ultrasone readings are way off and all over the place.

Does anybody have an idea what could cause this?

Snippet from code displaying the while loop with getting distance. As you can see the noObstacle command is commented out because this writes the serial command which causes the problem:

```
while True:
    distanceOne = getDistance(TRIGONE, ECHOONE)
    distanceTwo = getDistance(TRIGTWO, ECHOTWO)
    distanceThree = getDistance(TRIGTHREE, ECHOTHREE)
    distanceFour = getDistance(TRIGFOUR, ECHOFOUR)
    if (distanceOne and distanceTwo and distanceThree and distanceFour) > distanceThreshold:
        printNoObstacle = True
        #noObstacle()
    else:
        printNoObstacle = False
        #obstacle()
    print ("Distance 1: ", distanceOne,"Distance 2: ", distanceTwo,"Distance 3: ", distanceThree,"Distance 4: ", distanceFour, "cm", "noObstacle: ", str(printNoObstacle))
```

example output running above snippet, there is some noise but this feels accurate to me:

```
Distance 1:  536.0846996307373 Distance 2:  1576.941466331482 Distance 3:  1512.1204733848572 Distance 4:  109.37750339508057 cm noObstacle:  True
Distance 1:  535.7248783111572 Distance 2:  1576.569378376007 Distance 3:  1574.668049812317 Distance 4:  109.7577691078186 cm noObstacle:  True
Distance 1:  1561.8698596954346 Distance 2:  1576.409912109375 Distance 3:  1573.335075378418 Distance 4:  109.87634658813477 cm noObstacle:  True
Distance 1:  536.5099430084229 Distance 2:  1576.1032462120056 Distance 3:  1573.5190749168396 Distance 4:  109.83954668045044 cm noObstacle:  True
Distance 1:  536.538565158844 Distance 2:  1576.5939116477966 Distance 3:  1573.0284094810486 Distance 4:  109.39794778823853 cm noObstacle:  True
Distance 1:  536.8411421775818 Distance 2:  1576.2627124786377 Distance 3:  1573.1674313545227 Distance 4:  96.6038465499878 cm noObstacle:  True
```

When I enable the serial commands like so, sensor readings are all over the place:

```
while True:
    distanceOne = getDistance(TRIGONE, ECHOONE)
    distanceTwo = getDistance(TRIGTWO, ECHOTWO)
    distanceThree = getDistance(TRIGTHREE, ECHOTHREE)
    distanceFour = getDistance(TRIGFOUR, ECHOFOUR)
    if (distanceOne and distanceTwo and distanceThree and distanceFour) > distanceThreshold:
        printNoObstacle = True
        noObstacle()
    else:
        printNoObstacle = False
        obstacle()
    print ("Distance 1: ", distanceOne,"Distance 2: ", distanceTwo,"Distance 3: ", distanceThree,"Distance 4: ", distanceFour, "cm", "noObstacle: ", str(printNoObstacle))
```

Example of sensor data all over the place:

```
Distance 1:  86.7292046546936 Distance 2:  164.695942401886 Distance 3:  82.86521434783936 Distance 4:  30.294501781463623 cm noObstacle:  True
Distance 1:  79.61455583572388 Distance 2:  106.74426555633545 Distance 3:  98.30482006072998 Distance 4:  -4.689943790435791 cm noObstacle:  False
Distance 1:  214.60888385772705 Distance 2:  -5.945229530334473 Distance 3:  711.2849712371826 Distance 4:  78.39198112487793 cm noObstacle:  True
Distance 1:  79.67588901519775 Distance 2:  128.2558560371399 Distance 3:  102.32009887695312 Distance 4:  30.72383403778076 cm noObstacle:  True
Distance 1:  76.07358694076538 Distance 2:  144.4069266319275 Distance 3:  96.36669158935547 Distance 4:  27.154242992401123 cm noObstacle:  True
Distance 1:  79.47553396224976 Distance 2:  166.9284701347351 Distance 3:  94.11780834197998 Distance 4:  30.74427843093872 cm noObstacle:  True
Distance 1:  76.88727378845215 Distance 2:  104.66302633285522 Distance 3:  102.94160842895508 Distance 4:  -1.5455961227416992 cm noObstacle:  False
```

The whole code so you can also see the serial commands and the rest:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import serial
from signal import *
import sys
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Set up serial port
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyACM0',baudrate = 115200,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=1)

# Define ports
TRIGONE = 21    # count pin 1 rechtsonder
ECHOONE = 20    # count pin 2 rechtsonder
TRIGTWO = 26     # count pin 2 linksonder
ECHOTWO = 19     # count pin 3 linksonder
TRIGTHREE = 13  # count pin 4
ECHOTHREE = 6  # count pin 5
TRIGFOUR = 22   # count pin 13 
ECHOFOUR = 27   # count pin 14 

distanceThreshold = 20.0
minThreshold = 0.0
maxThreshold = 50000.0

setMotorMode = '^RWD 1 0\r'
standStillOne = '!g 1 0\r'
standStillTwo = '!g 2 0\r'
forward = '!g 1 200\r'
backward = '!g 1 -200\r'
turnLeft = '!g 2 200\r'
turnRight = '!g 2 -200\r'


def serialWrite(command):
    ser.write(command.encode())

def prepare():
    # Set Roboteq Motor mode (!g 1 0 now means motor off)
    serialWrite(setMotorMode)

    GPIO.cleanup()
    # Define in and out
    GPIO.setup(TRIGONE,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(ECHOONE,GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(TRIGTWO,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(ECHOTWO,GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(ECHOTHREE,GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(TRIGTHREE,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(ECHOFOUR,GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(TRIGFOUR,GPIO.OUT)

    # Settle down
    GPIO.output(TRIGONE, False)
    GPIO.output(TRIGTWO, False)
    GPIO.output(TRIGTHREE, False)
    GPIO.output(TRIGFOUR, False)
    print ("Waiting For Sensors To Settle")
    time.sleep(5)

def motorsOff():
    serialWrite(standStillOne)
    serialWrite(standStillOne)


# Making sure motors will be off when system kills process
def clean(*args):
    motorsOff()
    sys.exit(0)    
for sig in (SIGABRT, SIGINT, SIGTERM):
    signal(sig, clean)


def noObstacle():
    serialWrite(forward)


def obstacle():
    motorsOff()


def getDistance(GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO_ECHO):
    # set Trigger to HIGH
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)

    # set Trigger after 0.01ms to LOW
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)

    StartTime = time.time()
    StopTime = time.time()

    # save StartTime
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 0:
        StartTime = time.time()

    # save time of arrival
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 1:
        StopTime = time.time()

    # time difference between start and arrival
    TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime
    # multiply with the sonic speed (34300 cm/s)
    # and divide by 2, because there and back
    distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2

    return distance


if __name__ == "__main__":
    prepare()
    print('Now entering loop: ')
    try:
        while True:
            distanceOne = getDistance(TRIGONE, ECHOONE)
            distanceTwo = getDistance(TRIGTWO, ECHOTWO)
            distanceThree = getDistance(TRIGTHREE, ECHOTHREE)
            distanceFour = getDistance(TRIGFOUR, ECHOFOUR)
            if (distanceOne and distanceTwo and distanceThree and distanceFour) > distanceThreshold:
                printNoObstacle = True
                #noObstacle()
            else:
                printNoObstacle = False
                #obstacle()
            print ("Distance 1: ", distanceOne,"Distance 2: ", distanceTwo,"Distance 3: ", distanceThree,"Distance 4: ", distanceFour, "cm", "noObstacle: ", str(printNoObstacle))
            time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.cleanup()
    except Exception:
        motorsOff()
        raise
    finally:
        motorsOff()
```

Comment: How are we supposed to test/reproduce this?

Comment: I know, it's hard to test without peripherals, however maybe someone has an idea why the problem is happening. Maybe something to do with Raspberry Pi 3 having a hard time reading out 4 sensors and also sending commands over the USB serial interface